# Artifactory admin permissions

Tags: permissions, admin, artifactory

Does anyone know if it is possible to have restricted admin permissions for a helpdesk type user?

I'd like to have our helpdesk just be able to view/ edit users but not be able to change repos or any other config.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, admin users can manage everything in Artifactory. However, it is not possible to restrict a user to view/ edit users only.